# sonarqube backstage integration is failing

Tags: backstage

I am currently exploring backstage integration with our own sonarqube instance.
Followed instructions from:
https://github.com/backstage/backstage/tree/master/plugins/sonarqube
and
https://github.com/backstage/backstage/tree/master/plugins/sonarqube-backend

my config file is updated with:

```
proxy:
  '/sonarqube':
    target: https://sonarqube.gcp.xyz.com/api
    allowedMethods: ['GET']
    auth: <<token from sonarqube>>
sonarQube:
  baseUrl: https://sonarqube.gcp.xyz.com
  apikey: <<token from sonarqube>>
```

i am testing app in local using yarn dev command and i see no errors for sonarqube.

```
[1] 2022-11-16T03:53:35.856Z proxy info [HPM] Proxy created: /sonarqube  -> https://sonarqube.gcp.cna.com/api type=plugin
[1] 2022-11-16T03:53:35.857Z proxy info [HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api/proxy/sonarqube/?" ~> "/" type=plugin
```

some where in the log i see following statement.

```
[1] 2022-11-16T03:54:14.347Z backstage info 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2022:03:54:14 +0000] "GET /api/sonarqube/instanceUrl?instanceKey= HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.52" type=incomingRequest
```

Issue:
I don't see the sonar api working. I see following error. The key mentioned is present in the sonarqube baseUrl instance.

```
No information to display
There is no SonarQube project with key 'jupiter-camunda'.
```

please help be debug this issue. Logs are not helpful in finding what is wrong. is it poiting to the baseurl i provided or going to sonarqube.org ?

How to get this working.

Initially I tried with just sonarqube plugin, got same result. So tried adding sonarbackend and no success either.

Comment: did you get any solution out of this? i am struggling on exact error.

Comment: Did you go to https://sonarcloud.io/projects and look for the project key 'jupiter-camunda' ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a  similar issue the documentation isn't great and you only really need to follow the steps in the backend, first, you need to fix your `app-config.yaml` file.

1. Remove the proxy definition it doesn't actually need it.
2. Correct the case on sonarqube to fully lowercase as per below (match the backend docs)

   ```
   sonarqube:
     baseUrl: https://sonarqube.gcp.xyz.com
     apikey: <<token from sonarqube>>
   ```
3. Double check you have correctly installed the backend as per https://github.com/backstage/backstage/tree/master/plugins/sonarqube-backend

Comment: I'm also having issues to integrate this plugin. Did you had to create a plugin as indicated in the documentation your shared?

Comment: did not help me.